# Group date by date and count rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a log table.
I want to generate a fancy graph where we can see the total logs counts per day.

The output I want =

```
2014-01-05 => 1
2014-01-06 => 6
```

Where the first is the date then the totals logs within that date.

I currently have this

```
Log.order('created_at desc').limit(60).group('created_at')
```

Can't figure it out, if you guys would help me :)

Log example:

```
#<Log id: 33533, user_id: 94, category: 19, sub_category: 15147, data: {}, created_at: "2014-12-14 11:40:32", updated_at: "2014-12-14 11:40:32">
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want to group by date, just tell the database that and let it do the work:

```
Log.group('created_at::date').count
```

The `::date` is the PostgreSQL syntax for casting a timestamp to a date. You could also use standard SQL casting syntax:

```
Log.group('cast(created_at as date)').count
```

That should do everything in UTC, if you need a different time zone then adjust the GROUP BY clause.

You won't necessarily get a Hash in the right order from that, you can either sort the Hash in Ruby or use a subquery if you need the database to do the sorting.

Comment: How do I only get the logs from the last 30 days then?

Comment: Add a `where` to restrict `created_at`, something like `where('created_at > :thirty_days', :thirty_days => 30.days.ago)` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Try this. This would give you a hash of log records for the last 7 days. Here the key would be the day and the value would be the array of Log records for that date. You can get the records for as many previous days as you want.

```
Log.where('created_at >= ?', 7.day.ago).group_by{|m| m.created_at.day }
```

You could just get the count for the individual array wherever you need them by the `count` method of array. Also if you need the whole date for the key then try below.

```
Log.where('created_at >= ?', 7.day.ago).group_by{|m| m.created_at.to_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") }
```

You could also use [groupdate](https://github.com/ankane/groupdate) gem for it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: And what happens if that query returns a lot of rows? Why are you trying to do something in Ruby that would be better done inside the database?

Comment: @muistooshort: You are probably right. I had a similar requirement somewhere and I needed the record details as well. So the solution suited my requirement but maybe here there can be a better solution. I have edited the answer.